# When will a dynamically added fragment be re-added?

Tags: android, android-fragments

The [Fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Example) shows an example of an activity dynamically adding a fragment in `onCreate(...)`:

```
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // During initial setup, plug in the details fragment.
        DetailsFragment details = new DetailsFragment();
        details.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, details).commit();
    }
```

This *almost* makes sense to me, except for one detail.  I thought the reason for checking `savedInstanceState == null` was that if the activity is being re-created, we can expect the framework to re-add the fragment for us.  However, I thought the framework would only do this if the fragment has a tag, and the example uses the version of `FragmentTransaction#add(...)` that does not take a tag.  So as I understand it, if this activity were recreated, it would not have a `DetailsFragment`.

Is my understanding wrong?  And if the framework does re-add the fragment, at what point in the activity's lifecycle is it guaranteed to have done so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I thought the framework would only do this [*re-add the fragment*] if the fragment has a tag

No. According to [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating) in "Adding a fragment to an activity" section:

> each fragment requires a unique identifier that the system can use to restore the fragment if the activity is restarted.

Thus, you have 3 possibilities to handle this: using an `unique id`, `unique tag` or **none of them**. Yes, neither of the previous two requirements.The purpose of adding a `tag` is to capture the fragment. This is useful if you want to retrieve it easily and play with it (such as performing transactions). However, **it's not required**.

When you use [`add(int, Fragment)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment)), it calls [`add(int, Fragment, String)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)) with a `null tag` at the 3rd parameter. Therefore, the system will use the ID of the container view instead (1st param in `add()`). Thus, the fragment is restored without any `id` or `tag` that you supplied but correctly handled by the system.

*Note: in reference of `add(int, Fragment, String)`, you can see this quote: "Optional tag name for the fragment, to later retrieve the fragment with `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(String)`" - How could it be optional if we need it to restore fragments? ;)*

> At what point in the activity's lifecycle is it guaranteed to have done so?

I cannot honestly respond on it, maybe someone has the right answer but, here's what I think.

As you can see in ["Handling configuration changes"](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ConfigurationChanges), when orientation (or any specific change) occurs on activity, it calls `onDestroy()` and directly `onCreate()`. At the point of (activity's) `onCreate()` is called, the child fragment will receive a callback in `onAttach()`. Beside, when the activity has received its `onCreate()` callback, a child fragment receives automatically a `onActivityCreated()` callback. After that, each method in activity will trigger the "exact" same child methods (`onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()`, `onStop()`).

Thus, I think the safe point is `onStart()`, because activity triggers directly the call of the fragment's method, you're sure that the fragment is attached to it and you can handle `onRestart() -> onStart()` to update the UI.

Comment: I wrote a test app and found that the fragment was restored even before the activity's `onCreate()` is called.  But I still wonder whether that's guaranteed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use tags with my Fragments and mine work just fine, I have the exact same test as you.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//fragment needs to be created
}

if (savedInstanceState != null) {
//fragment will automatically be there with no code
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Do you know *when* the fragment will be there?